# Prevent volume creation on docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile can contain `VOLUME /path` instruction. That means that when `docker run` is executed, docker creates automatically a volume and binds it to `/path` inside container.

I'd like to skip the automatic volume creation in some cases. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not once it's be added to the Dockerfile. I'd personally avoid doing volumes inside of the Dockerfile since it ends up creating anonymous volumes as you've seen, but also because it breaks attempts to modify that directory in child images or even later steps inside of the same Dockerfile.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I've seen some images where the `VOLUME` instruction seems more like an error than a useful feature. Just have to live with it then :)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a little late, but anyway, you can use [tmpfs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/) (if you uses Linux). It doesn't prevent mounting, but when the container stops, the `tmpfs` mount is removed, and files written there won't be persisted:

```
docker run --tmpfs /evil-dir image:tag
```

Intance of using `tmpfs` with Docker Compose:

```
services:
  my-cool-service:
    image: image:tag
    tmpfs:
      - /evil-dir
```